# After installing Windows update the session in HttpHandler does not work properly

Tags: session-cookies, saml, httphandler, windows-update

After installing Windows update 2020—KB4534273 and 2020-KB4535101 session in HttpHandler does not work properly.

For SAML2 authentication, when processing a response on the SP side, I verify the response versus the sent request. However, when processing an update after installing an update, I do not have an available session.
IDP is https, SP http.

My handler implementing interface IRequiresSessionState
 `public class Saml2Handler : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState`

The solution had worked before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the known issues in this Microsoft article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/system-web-samesite#known-issues

We had a similar issue after patching our servers, and it was related to the change to SameSite cookie handling and sessionState in the .NET Framework.

Our scenario was this - user arrives unauthenticated, we set a value in session, redirect them to an external site to authenticate, after which the user is sent back to our site via HTTP **POST**.  It was the fact they were coming back on a POST that caused the issue.

We found a couple workarounds:

1. Revert to pre-patch cookie behavior
   (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/system-web-samesite#reverting-net-472-behavior)
2. Keep the new cookie setting for sessionState and manually set a cookie (this has the advantage of keeping the new recommended default security settings on the session cookie)

```
    context.Response.AddHeader("set-cookie", $"cookiename=cookievalue; path=/; SameSite=None; Secure");
```

We went with option #2

Comment: Option 2 is the way. It helped me